# PostgreSQL 8.2 giving inconsistant exexcution times

Tags: database, database-performance

We are using PostgreSQL 8.2 and we are seeing a very strange behavior when we run queries in multiple threads.

We are running the same query with 5 simultaneous threads for a period of 1 hour. 
When we do this we see that the timings in to execute the query varies drastically in between the executions.

We have checked the execution plans, broken the query down and still we do not see anything that could point us in any right direction. However when we do the same test with PostgreSQL 9.4 we do not see such a drastic deviation.

Following is our test bench

CentOS6 , 8GB 8vCPU cloud instance
Following are the postgreSQL setting

```
max_connections = 150
 shared_buffers = 2GB
 temp_buffers = 16MB
 max_prepared_transactions = 300
 work_mem = 64MB
 maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
 effective_cache_size = 4GB
```

Following is the Query

```
SELECT rateplanid,STAYDATE,MIN(PRIORITY||':'||SELLRATE||'@'||COALESCE(STDNETRATE,0)||'@0@'||COALESCE(HIGHERRATE,'N')||'@0@0@'||COALESCE(RATECODE,'-')||'@'||COALESCE(PROFITMARKUP,0)||'@'||COALESCE(BASENETRATE,0)) 
FROM (  SELECT rateplanid,STAYDATE,  ( CASE WHEN (customerid=2791) THEN 1 WHEN (regionid=4 AND customerid=0) THEN 2 WHEN customerid=1 THEN 3 END ) AS PRIORITY,  round(cast(SELLRATE as numeric),0) as SELLRATE,  round(cast(COALESCE(STDNETRATE,0) as numeric),2)
AS STDNETRATE, HIGHERRATE AS HIGHERRATE,  COALESCE('-')  AS RATECODE,  round(cast(profitmarkup as numeric),2) as PROFITMARKUP,  COALESCE(FIXEDSELLRATE,0)    as  
BASENETRATE 

FROM xxx.rate_2016m1_a2

WHERE staydate>='2016-02-20' AND staydate<='2016-02-20'
AND rateplanid  in (4031,4032,4019,4020,4024,4025,4026,4027,24027,24028,24029,24033,24037,24030,24034,24038,4014,24032,
24031,4015,8131,8132,86663,86664,64855,64856,86665,86666,7916,7917,7918,25721,25722,48689,48690,48691,65456,39774,39166,
65457,65458,39792,5954,5953,6899,8333,6898,51250,88150,6366,75464,88151,6367,75465,88159,5159,75468,88160,5161,75469,88169,
5168,75473,88170,5169,75474,88152,8107,75466,88153,8108,75467,88174,8114,75483,88175,8115,75484,55086,55091,55090,55096,55095,
10770,10774,10775,10771,10772,10773,99066,732,764,99067,4393,4394,5227,5228,10397,10398,3798,3797,35043,10223,10224,4167,
4168,8537,8538,8541,8542,102361,102362,3401,3402,4493,4492,4337,4338,11352,11353) 
AND ( customerid=2791 OR (regionid=4 AND customerid=0) OR customerid=1 ) 
AND coalesce(STDNETRATE,15)>15  AND coalesce(SELLRATE,20)>20

) AS X 
GROUP BY rateplanid,STAYDATE ORDER BY rateplanid,STAYDATE
```

Following is the execution plan

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=8.53..8.62 rows=1 width=53) (actual time=5303.500..5492.684 rows=27828 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=8.53..8.53 rows=1 width=53) (actual time=5303.430..5317.002 rows=37531 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: rate_2016m1_a2.rateplanid, rate_2016m1_a2.staydate"
"        ->  Index Scan using idx_rate_2016m1_a2_staydate on rate_2016m1_a2  (cost=0.00..8.52 rows=1 width=53) (actual time=53.857..5142.824 rows=37531 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((staydate >= '2016-02-20'::date) AND (staydate <= '2016-02-20'::date))"
"Total runtime: 5503.289 ms"
```

And following is the log output

```
XML - Date: 2016-02-02 rate query execution time : 2211
XML - Date: 2016-02-12 rate query execution time : 2232
XML - Date: 2016-02-10 rate query execution time : 2228
XML - Date: 2016-02-08 rate query execution time : 2224
XML - Date: 2016-02-04 rate query execution time : 2218
XML - Date: 2016-02-06 rate query execution time : 2208
XML - Date: 2016-02-07 rate query execution time : 5
XML - Date: 2016-02-13 rate query execution time : 13
XML - Date: 2016-02-05 rate query execution time : 5
XML - Date: 2016-02-09 rate query execution time : 4
XML - Date: 2016-02-11 rate query execution time : 5
XML - Date: 2016-02-03 rate query execution time : 4
XML - Date: 2016-01-25 rate query execution time : 27960
XML - Date: 2016-01-27 rate query execution time : 29843
XML - Date: 2016-01-29 rate query execution time : 33172
XML - Date: 2016-01-31 rate query execution time : 34075
XML - Date: 2016-02-01 rate query execution time : 705
XML - Date: 2016-01-26 rate query execution time : 10491
XML - Date: 2016-01-30 rate query execution time : 8584
XML - Date: 2016-01-28 rate query execution time : 12473
```

However when we run using PostgreSQL 9.4

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=0.58..1458.11 rows=2 width=50) (actual time=0.169..134.378 rows=98 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: rate_2016m1_a2.rateplanid, rate_2016m1_a2.staydate"
"  ->  Index Scan using uk_key_rate_2016m1_a2 on rate_2016m1_a2  (cost=0.58..1456.43 rows=19 width=50) (actual time=0.065..133.312 rows=98 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((rateplanid = ANY ('{4031,4032,4019,4020,4024,4025,4026,4027,24027,24028,24029,24033,24037,24030,24034,24038,4014,24032,24031,4015,8131,8132,86663,86664,64855,64856,86665,86666,7916,7917,7918,25721,25722,48689,48690,48691,65456,39774,3 (...)"
"        Filter: ((COALESCE(stdnetrate, 15::double precision) > 15::double precision) AND (COALESCE(sellrate, 20::double precision) > 20::double precision) AND ((customerid = 2791) OR ((regionid = 4) AND (customerid = 0)) OR (customerid = 1)))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 4"
"Planning time: 1.037 ms"
"Execution time: 134.501 ms"
```

Logged timings

```
XML - Date: 2016-02-06 rate query execution time : 1627
XML - Date: 2016-02-04 rate query execution time : 1622
XML - Date: 2016-02-08 rate query execution time : 1638
XML - Date: 2016-02-10 rate query execution time : 1645
XML - Date: 2016-02-12 rate query execution time : 1659
XML - Date: 2016-02-07 rate query execution time : 90
XML - Date: 2016-02-11 rate query execution time : 177
XML - Date: 2016-02-09 rate query execution time : 189
XML - Date: 2016-02-05 rate query execution time : 209
XML - Date: 2016-02-13 rate query execution time : 268
XML - Date: 2016-02-02 rate query execution time : 1967
XML - Date: 2016-02-03 rate query execution time : 40
XML - Date: 2016-01-29 rate query execution time : 3091
XML - Date: 2016-01-25 rate query execution time : 3195
XML - Date: 2016-01-31 rate query execution time : 3148
XML - Date: 2016-01-30 rate query execution time : 51
XML - Date: 2016-01-27 rate query execution time : 3147
XML - Date: 2016-01-30 rate query execution time : 51
XML - Date: 2016-01-27 rate query execution time : 3147
```

Right now we are stuck and any help in shedding some light into this issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're still using PostgreSQL 8.2? It's kind of been out of support for many moons. I assume the upgrade is not an option?

Comment: Completely agreed and this is a legacy system, we are in the process of modernizing this however that will take time. This issue is hitting us right now in our production environment.